# Send mail if the condition is achieved

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a database that receives values ​​from some sensors (eg. temperature), this database receives this data every 20 seconds, my goal is to send an email each that the value of the temperature sensor passes 26 ° C, after the program must be maintained for 10 minutes, since if it does not stop it will send the mail while the value of the temperature sensor remains above 26 ° C. The mail is sent correctly but the following two problems:

1 ° The program does not stop, when the program begins to run, the emails are sent without limits, while the value stays above 26 ° C.

2 ° Although the value is less than or greater than 26 is sent.

**This is the code**

```
def func1(x):
    dataSQL = []

    sql_conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'DB')
    cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT value FROM sensorParser where sensor='TC'")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        dataSQL.append(list(row))
        labels = ['value']
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dataSQL, columns=labels)
        Y = df['value'].astype(float)


        if ((Y) > 26.00).any():
            email = 'correo@gmail.com'
            password = 'pass'
            send_to_email = 'correo2@gmail.com'
            subject = 'ALERTA!!!!'
            message = 'Los valores de las variables criticas han superado el limite'
            file_location = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\prograpython\\image.jpg'

            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = email
            msg['To'] = send_to_email
            msg['Subject'] = subject

            msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

            filename = os.path.basename(file_location)
            attachment = open(file_location, "rb")
            part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
            part.set_payload((attachment).read())
            encoders.encode_base64(part)
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

            msg.attach(part)

            server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
            server.starttls()
            server.login(email, password)
            text = msg.as_string()
            server.sendmail(email, send_to_email, text)
            server.quit()
     reactor.callLater(20, func1, "hello")

reactor.callLater(20, func1, "hello")
reactor.run()
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` condition is not correct.

```
if ((Y) > 26.00).any():
```

should be something like this instead.

```
if y > 26.0:
```

Comment: It return me this: builtins.ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().